# facebook API v2.7 in node.js how to get comments and likes count

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to make a request fetching  share_count, like_count, comment_count,
        total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid and click_count from my node.js server using the new facebook api v2.7 .

what i came out with until now is :
         var likesCount=0;
        var commentCount=0;
        var shareCount=0;
        rp(graphApiReq, { json: true })
            .then(res => {
                commentCount = res.share.comment_count;
                shareCount = res.share.share_count;
                let graph_id = res.og_object.id;
                let likesApiReq = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/${graph_id}/likes?summary=true&access_token=${appId}|${appSecret}`;
                rp(likesApiReq, { json: true })
                    .then(likesRes => {
                        likesCount = likesRes.summary.total_count;
                    })
                response.send({likesCount,commentCount,shareCount});
            })

so basically i have here 2 calls :
1. to fetch the comments count which in a weird way is always 0 , and the share count , which actually works , using this request : 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?id=${url}/&access_token=${appId}|${appSecret}`;

2. to get the likes count,which in a weird way is also always 0 , i had to preform another call using the graph id coming from the first call ,
   `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/${graph_id}/likes?summary=true&access_token=${appId}|${appSecret}`

any ideas?do i really need those 2 calls ? why the results are always 0?

thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields

Answer (score 1):

I think your access token should not be ${app_id}|${app_secret}.

You should rather use the app_id and app_secret to authorize in front of facebook in order to receive an actual access_token which you can further use as parameter in the call you are trying to make.

Comment: hey , thanks but the access token seems to work ok its just that i cant get all the parameters i want : `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?id=${url}/likes_count,comment_count,share_count&access_token=${app_id}|${app_secret}`;

Comment: also tried to do this : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/${url}/?fields=likes.summary(true)&access_token=${app_id}|${app_secret} and it gave me back : "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (URL)",

Comment: And what about that surprises you? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/url lists the valid fields for that endpoint.

Comment: few things surprises me : 1 . comment_count is always 0 . 2. when i take the graph id and preform another request  graph.facebook.com/v2.7/${graph_id}/likes?summary=true . total_count which is the likes count is always 0 as well . 3. why do i need to preform 2 calls in order to fetch the likes# of this URL . kinda weird